# Is an exponentiable fibration with contractible fibers a homotopy equivalence?

Tags: ct.category-theory, homotopy-theory, higher-category-theory

**Question:** Let $p : E \to B$ be an [exponentiable](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Conduch%C3%A9+functor) functor of $\infty$-categories. Suppose that for every $b \in B$, the geometric realization of the fiber $|p^{-1}(b)|$ is contractible. Then does $p$ induce an equivalence of geometric realizations $|p| : |E| \to |B|$?

**Notes:**

- If $p$ is a locally cartesian fibration or a locally cocartesian fibration, then the answer is *yes* by Quillen's Theorem A plus the fact that the fibers are reflective in the lax slices (or dually).
- Since exponentiable fibrations are a common generalization of cartesian and cocartesian fibrations, one might hope for an affirmative answer here.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The answer is no in general. A counterexample is the codiagonal functor $\Delta^1 \cup_{\partial\Delta^1} \Delta^1 \to \Delta^1$. This is an exponentiable fibration (as is every functor with codomain $\Delta^1$) with contractible fibres, but its domain has geometric realization $S^1$ and its codomain is contractible.

Comment: Sorry when this is obvious, but why is every morphism with codomain $\Delta^1$ exponentiable?

Comment: @MartinBrandenburg This follows from the intrinsic characterisation of exponentiable functors (e.g. as "flat inner fibrations" of Appendix B.3 in Lurie's *Higher Algebra*) which quantifies over factorizations of morphisms in the codomain. Alternatively it follows from Joyal's theorem (Theorem 7.9 in [these lecture notes](https://mat.uab.cat/~kock/crm/hocat/advanced-course/Quadern45-2.pdf)) that the slice category $\mathbf{sSet}/\Delta^1$ equipped with the model structure induced from the model structure for quasi-categories is cartesian closed as a model category.